# How does GROUP BY work on Ambiguous columns?

Tags: sql

While practicing my SQL, I noticed something strange about GROUP BYs. I was working on a practice problem where we need to obtain the users with the most friends in a social network. Fairly straightforward.

We could have a nested sub-query which computes the number of friends for each user. (This would be done with a GROUP BY). Then match this up with our original Users table. The following query does just that.

```
select name, grade
from (select id1 as id, count(*) as c 
      from friend 
      group by id1)
JOIN Highschooler using (id)
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

What I don't understand is: why does the following query return the same thing?

```
select Highschooler.name, COUNT(*) as FriendCount
from friend
JOIN Highschooler ON (friend.ID1 = Highschooler.ID)
group by Highschooler.id
ORDER BY FriendCount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

There are multiple values of Highschooler.name, does SQL just pick one from the group? Secondly, which of the above two queries is preferred?

Comment: You would have to show sample data and results for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? It also depends on whether `id` is the primary key of the table `highschooler`. If it's not, the second query would be invalid SQL. And if it is, only Postgres and MySQL would accept it.

Comment: Btw: none of your statements is using a "sub-query". The first one uses a join on a derived table, not a sub-query

Answer (score 0):

Both queries will return the same results as in first query you are grouping first and then joining on id. In second one you are joining first and then grouping. This will make no difference.

However, Sub-queries are the logically correct way to solve problems of the form, "Get facts from A, conditional on facts from B". Some query engines prefer join, some prefer subquery.  As per the history join is better than subquery.

In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

Comment: "*As per the history join is better than subquery.*" - a sub query and a join are not necessarily equivalent. And _if_ they are nearly all modern DBMS optimizers will generate the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

There is sure number of ways to derive a result in sql. I would prefer join as this is cleaner and straight-forward, however, there will be instances that sub queries/nested are required. it is really a case by case basis. As long as you are getting the correct output and you have written your query logically, it should be fine.

You can also check the execution plan on your query to confirm which is more optimize.